# How can I know which program msiexec.exe is trying to install?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installer

Each time I try to install a program on my computer (running windows 7 RC), a setup.exe dialog pops up:

> The Windows Installer service is
>   unavailable. Another application may
>   be rerunning setup. Finish any
>   installations in progress, or restart
>   your computer, and then re-run setup.

I did restart a few times, and there's no ongoing installation I can think of.

If I pop up a task manager, I can indeed see a msiexec.exe process. I can kill it, but it will immediately start again. Is there a way to determine which program is installing and to abort it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). It should tell you what the program is, and also lets you kill it.

Answer (score 2):

[This Microsoft Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) will clean the partially installed programs.

Comment: The tool is deprecated now. Microsoft recommends to use Microsoft Fix it (http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/en) instead. It helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to kill msiexec.exe right before launching the other setup. Since msiexec.exe starts again by itself, the timeframe is quite tight, but it's definitely feasible...

Only a dirty workaround, though.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this works on 7 (probably does) but you can [turn on MSI logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314852).  My guess is Automatic Updates is stuck.

You usually have to turn on logging to get any information from MSI but there may be a few hints in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the windows application event log. MSI installations often show detailed errors inside these log files.